# In Jasig CAS 4.0.0, how to logout specified user?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas, jasig

My scenario is user A already logged on "admin". user B try to log in as "admin", customAuthenticationHandler found "admin" is logged on and return error Exception( this part done).

after that, how to log out the "admin" in CAS?

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<Ticket> list = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
        list.addAll(ticketRegistry.getTickets());
        for( Ticket x : list )
        {
            TicketGrantingTicketImpl ticket = (TicketGrantingTicketImpl) x;
            String name = ticket.getAuthentication().getPrincipal().getId();
            if(username.equals(name))
            {
                logoutManager.performLogout(ticket);
            }
        }
```

get the ticketRegistry and logoutManager, find out the name and do performLogout.